# How to know the subnet name which is attached to a VM in Azure PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine

How can I check which subnet is attached to my VM with azure power shell?
I don't see any property to get subnet name.

I have tried to Get-AzureRmVM but there is no information about a subnet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following command will work if you have the name of the VM's NIC:

```
(Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -name "VM_NIC Name").ipconfigurations.subnet.id
```

You can get the NIC ID from the following if you don't already have it:

```
(Get-AzureRmVM -name "VM Name").networkprofile.networkinterfaces.id
```